# How to findViewById() in Android parent fragment (getting a ClassCastException)?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-edittext

In my Android app I've got an EditText to which I want to do a setError() when it is empty. The EditText is located in a file called fragment_amount.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_amount"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    />
```

and I load this in a Fragment like so:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_amount, null);
}
```

From within the parent fragment of the fragment in which this EditText is initially loaded (using the snippet above) I now want to use setError like so:

```
EditText amountField = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment_amount);
amountField.setError("ERRROROROROR");
```

Unfortunately, I get a ClassCastException on the first line, saying: `android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText`. The strange thing it that in the fragment in which I initially load this EditText (AmountFragment.java), it is loaded in exactly the same way, without any errors.

Does anybody know how I can load this EditText in the parent fragment as an EditText so that I can use the setError() method? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Maybe you should use getParentFragment().getView() insted, but I'm not sure. Have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

You have given the name `fragment_amount` for your `layout` and also you have given the same name as `id` for your `edittext`.

So, try changing the `id` for your `edittext` in both xml and java.(For example, here i have given as `fragment_amount_edit`)

**XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_amount_edit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    />
```

**JAVA :**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_amount, null);

EditText amountField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_amount_edit);
amountField.setError("ERRROROROROR");

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some times the same name of layout or any other widget can be conflicted.

In your code there is same id of **EditText** is **fragment_amount** and same layout name as **fragment_amount**. So it is being conflicted.

Change from here:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_amount, null);
```

Now you are inflating your layout to View. So object of that View must be referenced to find the id of EditText. So

```
EditText edt= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.youreditId);
edt.setError("ERRROROROROR");

 return view;
}
```